# VS Code tasks.json automation

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Are there any methods to auto-generate a tasks.json file when an extension is launched? As it currently stands, a user must copy and paste in the same script for building each individual project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by removing the requirement for tasks.json entirely. I automatically run the "task" in typescript using the cp.execFile() command when the extension is activated.